# How to clear a log file in ubuntu on command, maybe with R?

Tags: r, bash, logging, ubuntu-14.04, logrotate

I still have a lot to learn about bash and unix commands...

I would like to take a log file that updates frequently,

```
ping    139.130.4.5 | tee /home/ping.log
```

I want to be able to take this log file and push it to my favorite cloud service using API packages in R, then clear the file so I don't get duplicate results while the log file continues to be written to.  How can I clear this file when it is being written to very frequently?  When I try to do this in R with `write` or `writeLines` with an empty character "" or character() the log continues to be written to but looks corrupted because it is showing bytes.

```
4865 6c6c 6f0a 576f 726c 640a 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

I've used `chardet` and both files show as ascii.  I thought it might be an encoding issue but I'm stuck at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clear your file with Bash :

```
> /home/ping.log
```

I don't know R but you may also try to delete the file after pushing it and recreate it.

Comment: I like the syntax of truncate more. Is there anything different between the two methods?

Comment: No, both create an empty file.

Answer (score 1):

Use `bash` `truncate` command after pushing it to cloud services.

```
truncate /home/ping.log --size 0
```

From the `man` page

> NAME
>          truncate - shrink or extend the size of a file to the specified size
>
> -s, --size=SIZE
>          use this SIZE

Comment: I like the syntax of this more than "> /home/ping.log" but is there anything different between the two?

Comment: I guess they both end up doing the same.